# Multiple calls on ngIf attribute - Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

Why when clicking on any elements of the material toolbar or even outside of it (other components) causes multiple checks of the `ngIf` attribute? A simple click can cause 10-20 calls. A simple filling out of a sign-in form can end up to hundreds of calls ... It isn't normal, is it?

Maybe I went wrong by placing  `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` inside the material  `<mat-sidenav-content></mat-sidenav-content>` ?

**main-nav.component.html** (this component resides in app.component.html)

```html
  <mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav #drawer class="sidenav" fixedInViewport="true" [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
    [mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'" [opened]="!(isHandset$ | async)">
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">Menu</mat-toolbar>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 3</a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <mat-toolbar color="primary" class="toolBarContainer">
      <button type="button" aria-label="Toggle sidenav" mat-icon-button (click)="drawer.toggle()" *ngIf="isHandset$ | async">
        <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <span class="likeALink" (click)="onClickLogo()">SimpleCRM</span>
      <p>
        <span id='location'>{{Location}}</span>
      </p>

      <ng-template [ngIf]="!authService.isAuthenticated()">
        <button routerLink="/sign-up" id="sign-up-button" mat-stroked-button>sign-up</button>
        <button routerLink="/sign-in" mat-stroked-button>sign-in</button>
      </ng-template>

      <button class="likeALink" id="logOut" *ngIf="authService.isAuthenticated()" mat-stroked-button (click)="logOut()">log-out</button>

    </mat-toolbar>
    <div>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Comment: It's called change detection and there's a lot of material out there to read up on it.

Comment: @IngoBürk Saying change detection doesn't help. I think OP wants to know why is ngIf triggering multiple time (20times) per click, instead of just 1, given that in angular 2+ change detection stablized in just one pass. It a valid question.

Comment: Angular still has to execute the function in every single change detection cycle to figure out if the value changed. And assuming this isn't a production build, things get worse since Angular will call it twice every time. My point stands that there is a lot to read up on here since OP doesn't seem familiar with CD at all at the moment.

Comment: Ok. I read an [article](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/change-detection/) on change detection and [hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) Well I understand that change detection goes down the tree from root to child components. And to avoid so many CD I should implement CD strategy "on push" and I should then make sure that `@Input`  properties will receive immutable objects. And in a parent component I should assign a new object rather then changing some properties of an old obj. But in my case the component in which I see so much checks depends not on incoming

Comment: property from a parent component but from a return value of a function in a service. I rewrote the code that now in my auth service I have a `public isAuthenticated = new Subject<boolean>();` and in `main-nav.component` I subscribe to it in ngOnInit and then assign returned boolean to a property in `main-nav.component`. Thus ngIf will check a simple boolean property. But still I won't skip the checks. This way I only drop multiple function calls?

Answer (score 1):

Angular handles the binding between the model and the dom (component and template file). To do this the application ticks (change detection cycle) and checks for if any values that have changed, and if so -> Update the dom.

The problem is when you have functions in your template file, and each cycle angular will call the function to check if the 'value' has changed.

For example, if I had a simple get function which only returned a value, Angular needs to run it to check that there is actually a change.

```
{{ myValue() }} // in the template file

myValue() { return 10 } // in the component
```

Here it makes sense that angular must call the function each to check if the value has changed.

A solution (if you don't want Angular to be constantly calling your functions), is to implement a ChangeDectionStrategy (https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy).
With this, you can tell Angular that you will handle the updates, and when it should run the cycle (for only that component).

To do so within the component metadata you will add the following:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  templateUrl: './table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush // the new line
})
```

Then in the constructor:

```
constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
```

Whenever you make a change, you can then call **this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();** which will manually run the cycle for this component and update the dom when needed.

I really suggest reading into this more as the topic is too broad to describe in this one post

---

**Another solution**
Instead of implementing change detection, instead of using a function to get the value for the *ngIf. You use a public variable in the component file. Then you overwrite it, when it changes.

```
public authenticated: boolean = false; // use this variable in the template instead of the function

afunction() { // you will have to decide when you can reliably call this
  this.authenticated = isAuthenticated(); 
}
```

---

***Duplicate of***: [Angular5 template binding, callback function called more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48960408/angular5-template-binding-callback-function-called-more-than-once/49147348#49147348)

Comment: Very helpful answer! Thank you! I've read some articles on CD and they didn't mention than you can use `ChangeDetectorRef` and `this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();`  now after reading your post I've found [a good one](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html) with great illustrations of the CD process with explanation of the `markForCheck()`.

Comment: Very much welcome :)! Just be careful, because once you put changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush in the component meta data, you take control of updating the component. And will have to call markForCheck() whenever you want to force a update in the HTML. Good luck.